# Use one route to handle all CRUD request for different collections or create one route for each collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently working on a express API that connects with a local mongodb database.

In the Database I have multiple collection as "Customers", "Products", "Suppliers" and I want to make simple "insert" "findOne" or "find for Match" queries now my questions is:

It is okay to be creating a copy of function for each request/collection or should I make one controller which receive the collection from where the data must be "insert" "findOne" or "find for Match" for all the requests?

So with this question I looking to take care of my nodejs app size and performance.

Comment: Copying functions makes no sense.  Factor common code into a utility function that you can pass the collection name to and all the routes can use the same function.  As for one route or multiple routes, that really depends upon more context for what you're doing and the URL structure you are using.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.